# Getting Meta Author Tag with data Tags

Tags: blogger

I have a Blogger Blog with 4/5 Active Writers,
what i want to accomplish id there post have thier own Name in Meta Author Tag

So far i've done this

```
<meta expr:content='data:post.author' name='author'/>
```

This Tag can be viewed on Posts but when i Placed it to head section,
there i will get an error

Please help me with this issue as it good practice for SEO stuff

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you add the names of the authors in the  meta tags for the site description it could help.
I have numerous authors on one of my blogs,http://omemeeon.blogspot.com  but after a publishing fiasco, I now publish all posts myself, and tag each with the author's name. The authors submit their work in a private back office, or via email where I can edit their work prior to publishing.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
<div expr:content='data:post.author' name='author' />
```

meta tags are not used to print out something on your blog,but used to find author name for search engines